# How to add the Microsoft Office Interop in ssis c# script task

Tags: c#, ssis

In SSIS  script task ,I was trying to add the reference, Microsoft Office Interop Excel.Is it a service reference? It is not in the list of referenes

Comment: why not try to incorporate SSRS instead what exactly are you trying to accomplish.. ? can you please explain in a little bit more detail. also have you done a complete google search on the topic Using `Microsoft Interop Excel inside SSIS`...?

Comment: I am going to make a scipt component which convert an xlsx to csv.So ineed this reference

Comment: and have you thought about using SSIS to write the data to a DataTable and then convert the values to .csv or create the .csv directly from the data in SSIS.. using Interop to do this in my opinion is OverKill

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to Add Reference... in VS while editing the script, like you normally would. Click the Browse button. Look for the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll in the following directory (or at least, something like it).

`C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c`

This worked for me on my machine, and I am running Windows 10. I have no idea if this will be different on another machine. I have Excel installed, so you may need that as well.